# Should use of application/x-httpd-php .html be avoided for any reasons?

Tags: php, apache

I have a little custom framework. For my view files I was thinking of allowing php code inside of .html template files. Is there any downsides to setting AddType application/x-httpd-php .html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest downside is that ALL html files will be run through the PHP interpreter, which will likely slow down your server somewhat. Depending on your specific needs, that might not be a huge issue.

It could also be a security issue if you allowed people to upload HTML files to your website for some reason, but that is probably unlikely.

Any file that you put in an include() statement will be run through the PHP interpreter. So if you are running your views through the include statement you don't actually have to add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" to your config.

For example if you created a file named view.html that contained something like:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<p><?php echo 'hello world'; ?></p>
```

If you went to that file through the browser, it would appear exactly as above. If you did an include('view.html') in another PHP file, the PHP code would actually be executed.

Comment: I actually didn't know including html files would parse them as php. That was the reason I thought I needed to add the type to my config. But as you said, including works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **URL rewriting** to make user think that he/she is accessing html-suffixed files.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to weight everything out to make my final decision.